# Webpack code splitting causing jumpy animations on route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

So I am using code splitting to split my (rather large) application into manageable chunks, like so:

```
const getSettings = (nextState, cb) => {
  require.ensure([], require => {
    cb(null, require('../containers/Settings/Settings'))
  }, 'settings')
}
```

This is probably a pretty rudimentary way of getting Webpack to split at certain points, but it's worked for me so far.

*However, I've reached a serious setback*. Because these chunks are necessarily asynchronous, when entering a route which depends upon a non-fetched chunk, the actual route changes (via `react-router`), but it takes a few seconds for the actual children components to update, thus leaving a choppy animation.

How can I force `react-router` to not fire `LOCATION_CHANGE` until all necessary chunks have been loaded?

I am using `react-router 3.0.0` and `webpack 1.13.2`

Comment: Ooops! so cool 

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI What?

Comment: impressing by tech u are using

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? The current (v.2, v.3) has the [getComponent()](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback)/getComponents() API you should probably use. The next version (v.4 - seems to be be in beta and about to be released) is a different beast - haven't figured it out yet. Also I assume form the tag that you are using Webpack v.1 not v.2.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I am using `react-router 3.0.0` and `webpack 1.13.2`. The `getComponent` function does get a component async, but only _after_ calling `LOCATION_CHANGE`, and I have no way to know if the location change is going to require data (chunk) fetching...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue using `require.ensure` with `getComponent` with React Router 3. My solution seems dirty, but it does work. I have spots where I pre-fetch a bundle of components so they're available for the routes when they're instantiated.

It's just a function that `require.ensure`s the components - import and execute it. Still reduces your initial load which I'm assuming is a goal.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that's a great solution. My auth-required area involves a heavy (300kb) script that 50% of users will never need. There must be a way to have `react-router` call `LOCATION_CHANGE` in an async fashion...

Comment: I believe I found a solution for my own animation concerns, not sure if it helps you but feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, as expected, there was very little documentation/info from the community on such a niche issue as this.

The way I got around it was simpler than expected: I just listened for changes in my top level `App` components children as opposed to route changes, because route changes couldn't be trusted.

So it looks something like this:

```
<FadeProps animationLength={40}>
  <main style={styles.appContent} key={children.type.displayName}>
    {route.status === 200 && children}
    {route.status === 404 && <NotFound />}
  </main>
</FadeProps>
```

Notice the key is `this.props.children.type.displayName`, which will only actually change when the chunk has been loaded and the component is available. I was noticing 2-4 renders with the *old* component at the new route location, so children is the only data which can actually be trusted.